# swift - Comparing structs that conform to a protocol

Tags: swift, struct, iequatable

I have the following structs that represent a point or a line:

```
public struct Point{
    let x : Double
    let y : Double

    init (x : Double, y : Double)
    {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}
extension Point : Equatable{}
    public func ==(lhs: Point, rhs: Point) -> Bool
    {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
    }
```

And

```
public struct Line {
    let points : [Point]
    init(points : [Point])
    {
        self.points = points
    }
}

extension Line : Equatable {}
    public func ==(lhs: Line, rhs: Line) -> Bool
    {
        return lhs.points == rhs.points
    }
```

I want to be able to have a Shape protocol or struct that I can use to have Points and Lines and then I can compare between them. 
I tried to that with conforming protocol Shape but Swift compiler gives me an error when I want to compare a point with a line even though they are Shapes.

Do I have to move from struct to classes?
I think I may have to use generics but don't know exactly how to solve this issue. 
Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Edit1:

My approach to Shape protocol was really just trying stuff but nothing worked. I tried the following:

```
protocol MapShape : Equatable
{
      func == (lhs: MapShape, rhs: MapShape ) -> Bool
}
```

I also changed the code for the Equatable extension for lines given the suggestion

Comment: If I remember correctly, the WWDC 2015 video on "Swift Protocol Oriented Programming" covers this issue. (In any case, every Swift programmer should have seen that!)

Comment: What was your attempt at the shape struct? Please share it

Comment: Shared the protocol I tried to use and edited my code given your suggestion @Kametrixom

Comment: @Franklin I edited my answer, have another look, also a line just has a starting point and an end point, not an array of points, I edited my code like this as well

Comment: @Kametrixom true. I am modeling a Polyline... I need it to be as a collection of points. But your observation was really valid. Tks

Comment: Oh god i edited your question accidentaly, please mods or whatever reject my edit, pleassseeee Im so sorry, I wanted to edit my own answer but missclicked (you can't cancel edits that's why)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This topic is covered in the WWDC 2015 session video [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=408), and here is my attempt to apply that to your situation:

You define a protocol `Shape` and a protocol extension method
`isEqualTo:`:

```
protocol Shape {
    func isEqualTo(other: Shape) -> Bool
}

extension Shape where Self : Equatable {
    func isEqualTo(other: Shape) -> Bool {
    if let o = other as? Self { return self == o }
    return false
    }
}
```

`isEqualTo:` checks if the other element is of the same type (and compares them with `==` in that case), and returns `false` if they
are of different type.

All types which are `Equatable` automatically conform to `Shape`,
so that we can just set

```
extension Point : Shape { }
extension Line : Shape { }
```

(Of course you can add other methods to `Shape` which should be 
implemented by all shape types.)

Now we can define `==` for shapes as

```
func ==(lhs: Shape, rhs: Shape) -> Bool {
        return lhs.isEqualTo(rhs)
}
```

and voilà, points and lines can be compared:

```
let p1 = Point(x: 1, y: 2)
let p2 = Point(x: 1, y: 3)
let l1 = Line(points: [p1, p2])
let l2 = Line(points: [p1, p2])

print(p1 == p2) // false
print(p1 == l1) // false
print(l1 == l2) // true
```

---

*Remark:* You have `==` for the `Shape` type now, but I haven't figured out yet to how make `Shape` conform to `Equatable`. Perhaps someone
else can solve that part (if it is possible).

Comment: I understand that Shape does not conforms to Equatable but this solution will work for my case! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please allow me to shorten and correct your code a bit:

```
struct Point : Equatable {
    let x : Double
    let y : Double
}

func ==(lhs: Point, rhs: Point) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
}

struct Line : Equatable {
    let a : Point
    let b : Point
}

func ==(lhs: Line, rhs: Line) -> Bool {
    return lhs.a == rhs.a && lhs.b == rhs.b
}
```

I think I know now what you want:

```
protocol Shape : Equatable {

}


struct Polygon : Shape {
    let points : [Point]
}

func ==(lhs: Polygon, rhs: Polygon) -> Bool {
    return lhs.points == rhs.points
}



struct Circle : Shape {
    let center : Point
    let radius : Double
}

func ==(lhs: Circle, rhs: Circle) -> Bool {
    return lhs.center == rhs.center && lhs.radius == rhs.radius
}
```

Note: You have to implement `==` for every shape on its own, because every shape type has different properties

If you want every Shape to have a certain method, you can just add the requirement to the protocol:

```
protocol Shape : Equatable {
    func move(dx: Double, dy: Double) -> Self
}
```

and make every Shape conform to it:

```
struct Polygon : Shape {
    let points : [Point]

    func move(dx: Double, dy: Double) -> Polygon {
        return Polygon(points: points.map { Point(x: $0.x + dx, y: $0.y + dy) })
    }
}

struct Circle : Shape {
    let center : Point
    let radius : Double

    func move(dx: Double, dy: Double) -> Circle {
        return Circle(center: Point(x: center.x + dx, y: center.y + dy), radius: radius)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is how will I do in the future when instead of a Line I have a another shape that cannot be represented as an Array of points.

Comment: @Franklin You mean like a circle?

Comment: for example, yep. I could want to be able to represent a circle in the future if I needed to @Kametrixom

Comment: @Franklin Edited again, check it out

Comment: I tried that, the problem is that when I try to use: `let a : Shape = point ` it says: **protocol Shape can only be used as a generic because it has Self or associated Type requirements**

Comment: @Franklin Hmm... I have seen this problem before, but I don't know a solution right now